# Matching ^ and $ in Regular Expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am using regular expressions and I came across ^xxx and xxx$ meaning matches xxx regex at the beginning of the line and matches regex xxx at the end of the line.Can anybody please explaing this with example, I am having hard time understanding this

Comment: Not at the beginning of the _line_ but at the beginning of the _input_. Regex `^` will match before `foo` in `foo\nbar` but not before `bar`.

Comment: Unless the multiline mode is enabled.

Comment: Yes, that, but let's keep things simple for the OP which doesn't seem to grasp the concepts behind those anchors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to what method you are using to match.

If you use `String.matches()` then it will consider the *entire String* so specifying `^` or the `$` is quite useless.

If you are using `Pattern` and `Matcher` to match then you can use `^` and `$` like this :

Example : 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcabc";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(m.start()); // prints starting index of match
}
```

O/P :

```
true
0
```

Example : 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcabc";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(m.start()); // prints starting index of match
}
```

O/P :

```
true
3
```

Example -3 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "xxabc\nabc";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^abc");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(m.start());
}

false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)  --> OOPs.. Not at the beginning?
```

Answer (score 2):

This makes sense, if you looking for some parts of a string, like in this search and replace example:

```
System.out.println("test test test".replaceAll("^test", "TEST"));
System.out.println("test test test".replaceAll("test$", "TEST"));
```

Outputs

```
TEST test test
test test TEST
```

But if you try to match entire string you get `^` and `$` inserted automatically:

```
System.out.println("test test test".matches("test"));
System.out.println("test test test".matches("^test$")); // The same
```

and both return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`^xxx` matches all String wich start with `xxx`

- xxx1234   --> match
- xxxABDcx  --> match
- xxassas   --> no match

`xxx$` matches all strings ends with `xxx`

- 1234xxx --> match
- Acdsadsxx --> no match

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning**:

- `^` - Beginning of a document/string.
- `$` - End of a document/string.

**Brief examples**:

- *"find files whose authors have the obnoxious habit of typing a carriage returns at the end"*:

`\n$`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\n$");
String string1 = "This is a document.";
String string2 = "This is a document.\n";
Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(string1);
Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(string2);
System.out.println(matcher1.find());// false
System.out.println(matcher2.find());// true
```

- *"find documents that begin with a capital letter"*:

`^[A-Z]`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]");
String string1 = "This is a document.";
String string2 = "this is a document.";
Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(string1);
Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(string2);
System.out.println(matcher1.find());// true
System.out.println(matcher2.find());// false
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example would be:

```
System.out.println("abc".replaceAll("abc", "xxx")); 
System.out.println("abc".replaceAll("bc", "xx")); 
System.out.println("abc".replaceAll("^bc", "xx")); 
System.out.println("abc".replaceAll("bc$", "xx")); 
System.out.println("abc".replaceAll("^ab", "xx")); 
System.out.println("abc".replaceAll("ab$", "xx"));
```

And the output:

```
xxx
axx
abc
axx
xxc
abc
```

Where `x` represents when the chars are being matched.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
if (Pattern.matches("^123.*", "123blablabla")) {
  System.out.println("It matches!");
}
else {
  System.out.println("It does not match!");
}
```

will output:

> It matches!

because the string "123blablabla" starts with "123" and is followed by zero or more characters (".*" in regexp language).

In a similar way, the following code:

```
if (Pattern.matches(".*abc$", "some string that ends with abc")) {
  System.out.println("It matches!");
}
else {
  System.out.println("It does not match!");
}
```

will output

> It matches!

because the string "some string that ends with abc" ends with "abc".